# JavaScript API to detect Office language and Excel argument separator

Tags: ms-office, office-js

In Excel, from `formulasLocal` of a range, we could get more or less an idea about the user's language and number-formatting locale. For example, the English "=SUM(A1, 1.5)" formula would become "=SUMME(A1; 1,5)" in German.

But a workbook can well have no formula. So, is there a formal API to detect which language of Office (especially Excel) a user is using?

Additionally, is there a formal API to detect the argument separator (eg, `;` or `,`)?

Additionally again, is there a formal API to check if the workbook is under `R1C1` or `A1` notation style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 language values you can reference with the Office.js APIs. One is the [Context.displayLanguage](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.displaylanguage) (which returns the language of Office UI), and the other is [Context.contentLanguage](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.context.contentlanguage) (which returns the language of the data/text inside the document). Both of these can be configured separately by the users. The argument separator is determined by the content language.

It's not necessary to check whether the workbook is using R1C1 notation because when you set a formula you can simply use A1 notation and Excel will automatically convert it if needed.

Comment: Thank you... And what about the `R1C1` or `A1` notation style? in some (rare) cases, we cannot retrieve this information from a formula. For instance, `=SUM(R10)` can be interpreted differently in 2 modes...

Comment: just added an explanation of that: Excel converts it automatically, so just use A1 for setting it programmatically and you'll be fine.

Comment: But in some cases of add-in development, we do need to know what the workbook is using and how formulas **appear exactly and initially** to users. With the current `range.formulas`, `range. formulasLocal` and `range.formulasR1C1`, they always automatically convert to a certain mode...

Comment: Yeah, interesting, I can image how in some specific cases you might want to know what the appearance of a formula will be to a user, like I suppose if you want to implement a "previewer" for formulas, perhaps. We don't currently have an API to tell whether R1C1 notation is being used. A really hacky workaround would be to set the **value** of a cell to a formula (like "=R1C[2]") and then read the value back to see whether there's an error.

Comment: Indeed, this is what i am developing as add-in, and I am aware my questions are specific... One difficulty of using your workaround is that, users may change `R1C1` or `A1` style within one session. So I need a listener to know when the setting changes, and then I check what the setting is... Do we have an API for a setting change? Your workaround will work to detect the formula separator (eg, `;` or `,`) which does not change within one session. So you confirm that there is no formal API to detect the separator?

Comment: Correct, no formal API

Comment: I assume you referred to the separator... And no formal API for setting change?

Comment: Do you think [settingschangedevent](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings.settingschangedevent) can be used to detect the setting change of formula notation style?

Comment: No, that's not the type of Settings that the SettingsChanged event refers to.